# Print out the contents of node object in a node template

Tags: nodes, debugging

How do I print out the contents of the $node object in a node template in a way that is easily readable. I thought that `<?php dpr($node);?>` would do it but that doesn't seem to work in my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) have a tab that let you see all the options and elements in that node.

It helps you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
<?php
   print "<pre>";
   print_r($node);
   print "</pre>";
?>
```

Alternatively you can use below code too...

```
<?php
  drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($node, 1) . "</pre>");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To print specific fields in the template you can also try following code:

```
<?php print $node->field_name['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

To get the value of the body field of node try following code:

```
<?php print $node->body['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

For more clear understanding: 
`$node->field_name['und']` will be the Array of all the values of particular fields. So you can try and retrieve any field.

You can also use

```
<?php 
  print '<pre>;
  var_dump($node);
  print '</pre>';
?>
```

to see the detailed structure of node, as per suggestion of Anil Sagar.

Comment: I read somewhere that accessing stuff via ['und'] is not recomended because it is a field related to localisation http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way